# Spring alert() instead of redirect with response

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, alert

This application is in spring.  I'm unfamiliar with spring. Basically, everything is working, however, instead of redirecting to a new page that displays the "PurchaseResponse", I would like to just reload the mainscreen, and use the PurchaseResponse in an alert. Please see code for clarification.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/demo.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Okie Computers</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h1>Okie Computers</h1>
    <a href="/about.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">About Us</button></a>
    <hr>
    <h2>Parts</h2>
    <form th:action="@{/mainscreen}">
        Filter: <input type="text" name="partkeyword" id="partkeyword" size="50" th:value="${partkeyword}" required />
        &nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        &nbsp;
        <input type="button" value="Clear" id="btnClearPart" onclick="clearSearch()" />
    </form>
    <br><br>
    <a th:href="@{/showFormAddInPart}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3">Add Inhouse Part</a>
    <a th:href="@{/showFormAddOutPart}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3">Add Outsourced Part</a>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Inventory</th>
            <th>Action</th>
            <th>Buy Now</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="tempPart : ${parts}">
            <td th:text="${tempPart.name}">1</td>
            <td th:text="${tempPart.price}">1</td>
            <td th:text="${tempPart.inv}">1</td>
            <td><a th:href="@{/showPartFormForUpdate(partID=${tempPart.id})}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3">Update</a>
                <a th:href="@{/deletepart(partID=${tempPart.id})}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3"
                   onclick="if(!(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this part?')))return false">Delete</a>
<!--                <form th:action="@{/buyProduct(productID=${tempPart.id})}" method="post">-->
<!--                    <input type="submit" value="Buy Now" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3">-->
<!--                </form>-->
            </td>



        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <h2>Products</h2>
    <form th:action="@{/mainscreen}">
        Filter: <input type="text" name="productkeyword" id="productkeyword" size="50" th:value="${productkeyword}" required />
        &nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        &nbsp;
        <input type="button" value="Clear" id="btnClearProduct" onclick="clearSearch()" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function clearSearch() {
            window.location = "[[@{/}]]";
        }
    </script>
    <br><br>
    <a th:href="@{/showFormAddProduct}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3">Add Product</a>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Inventory</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="tempProduct : ${products}">
            <td th:text="${tempProduct.name}">1</td>
            <td th:text="${tempProduct.price}">1</td>
            <td th:text="${tempProduct.inv}">1</td>
            <td><a th:href="@{/showProductFormForUpdate(productID=${tempProduct.id})}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3">Update</a>
                <a th:href="@{/deleteproduct(productID=${tempProduct.id})}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3"
                   onclick="if(!(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this product?')))return false">Delete</a>
                <a th:href="@{/buyProduct/{productId}(productId=${tempProduct.id})}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3">Buy Now</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="mt-4" id="footer">
        <h5>&copy; 2023  </h5>
    </footer>
</div>
<scr>
    alert(PurchaseResponse)
</scr>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
package com.example.demo.controllers;

import com.example.demo.domain.Product;
import com.example.demo.repositories.ProductRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


@Controller
public class BuyProductController {

    private final ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    public BuyProductController(ProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/buyProduct/{productId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public PurchaseResponse buyProduct(@PathVariable("productId") Long productId) {
        Product product = productRepository.findById(productId).orElse(null);
        if (product != null) {
            int inventory = product.getInv();
            if (inventory > 0) {
                product.setInv(inventory - 1);
                productRepository.save(product);
                return new PurchaseResponse("Purchase successful");
            } else {
                return new PurchaseResponse("Product is out of stock");
            }
        }
        return new PurchaseResponse("Product not found");
    }
    private static class PurchaseResponse {
        private String message;

        public PurchaseResponse(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }

}
```

I've tried alerting the purchase

Comment: Which has nothing to do with Spring but rather how you code your front-end.